# Floating Labels stop working with Xamarin.Android.Support 25.1.0

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-support-library, mvvmcross

I have an odd issue after having to update to the Xamarin.Android.Support 25.1.0 libraries so I can use Firebase cloud messaging where with bound fields that have a value the floating label stops working. It seems ok in fields where they are bound but the value is null/empty. 
[image: Floating Label Fail]

This only happens with 25.1.0, I've avoided upgrading in the past and kept using 24.2.1 where I have not had this issue.

Any ideas on where the issue might be?

Comment: It's a bug in version 25.1.0. It was resolved in a later version, though. Upgrade again, if you can.

Comment: I can upgrade and that did fix it thankyou very much.